# How to implement a loading screen to prevent a user from interacting with the interface while doing background processing

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

In my new app I need to show a animation while doing some processing(e.g sending data to the server, reading data from a web service, etc).

Something like this:

[image]

This is what I used to do when I wanted to implement something similar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >   

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sincronizarSpinnerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout>

      <!--Main content here-->

    </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I have two **nested** relative layouts. The first layout is invisible (`android:visibility="gone"`) by default and I only make it visible when I start a Service, AsyncTask or asynchronous technique.

Although I have used this method in the past, now that my main layouts (the ones that should go inside the second relative layout) are more complicated, I'm not sure it'd be a good idea to make things even more complicated by adding another nesting level to my activity.

1. Is there any way I can avoid having to add another layout to all of
   my activities that need to display a spinner animation? Perhaps
   there's some kind of pattern or good practice I'm not aware of.
2. Do I really need to worry about adding another nesting level to my
       activity, knowing that I already have two or three levels?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `ProgressDialog` and use `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` so user cannot touch outside while your `AsyncTask` is working.

Here is my structure code that I use almost in my project that use `AsyncTask`. You can apply to your project:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private Context mContext;

    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Downloading", "Downloading Data ...");
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); // main method that force user cannot click outside
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dlg) {
                DownloadTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do some background work here

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (this.isCancelled()) {
            result = null;
            return;
        }

        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd change your structure to this -

```
<frame layout>
<spinner center in parent/>
<realtive layout>
<main content/>
</realtive layout>
</frame layout>
```

Does that make sense? Its ok to wrap the main content in a frame layout to add the progress spinner

Also, you can use the `<include>` tag to keep the xml files cleaner.
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot about <include>. That's a great idea!!! :)  By <frame> you mean <FrameLayout>?

Comment: yah, frame layout. it is more efficient then linear or realtive layouts.

Comment: I think it never occurred to me to use FrameLayout, because I always thought that it should always have a single child. But since only one view will be visible at a time(either the spinner or the relative layout) I guess that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

*This all depends on your use case.*

While displaying a loading indicator in the background is a good thing to do when loading a list, it might be irritating to hide everything and display a progress bar after clicking 'Submit' on a button.

So yes, one way *is* to use code like yours. You should although try optimizing your layouts, e.g. make use of `FrameLayout` where appropriate. But this is not the topic here.

Another way to *block user interaction* would be to display a progress dialog which can be further customized with a message:

```
// you can also set title / message
new ProgressDialog.Builder(this).setCancelable(false).show();
```

Also, you can just *disable* your UI elements. And enable them again after finishing your time consuming operations using

```
view.setEnabled(false); // disable view while doing work
```

Comment: But even the youtube app does that when it needs to load your subscriptions :(. So you would recommend using a ProgressDialog? TBH I only used that class when I used AsyncTasks for everything. Nowadays I try to stay away from AsyncTasks at all costs.

Comment: @eddy *It depends on your use case.* I listed 3 options, including the progressBar like the layout you show. You should pick whatever suits your use case best, and there is no general right or wrong since it is a design choice

Comment: Would `ProgressDialog` remain visible even if I leave the activity? When I use the approach described in my question,in the event `onResume()` I always check if my service is still running and change the `visibility` of the indicator accordingly. Would I be able to do something similar with `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: @eddy you would need to keep the instance of the dialog and cancel it when finishing, or leaving the activity.

Comment: In another answer I got, a user mentioned that in my case it'd be better to use `FrameLayout`. You also mentioned that. Would I improve performance if I used `FrameLayout` instead?

Comment: @eddy Yes, this is one of the ways to improve your layout. you should read on some tutorials about layouts and when to use them.

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442183/using-the-animated-circle-in-an-imageview-while-loading-stuff) out. Android does it for you, all you need is to make it "indeterminate" so it spins in an infinite loop until you call it off.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Show it like so:

`loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

and when done hide it:

`loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);`